# I need to use a method in two classes. which approach is a good practice? making a method public vs making it static vs making a duplicate

Tags: java, oop

I have two adapter classes that are in the same package where I need the following method..

```
private int getAlphaValue(int backgroundTransparency) {
    int backgroundOpaquePercentage = 100 - backgroundTransparency;
    int alpha= (255 * backgroundOpaquePercentage) / 100;
    return alpha;
}
```

1. Have a copy of this method in each of the classes and make them private.
2. Have the method in one of the classed and make it static and protected to be able to use in both methods

Which of the above two approaches is a good practice and an efficient one?

Comment: Have it declared as static in some Utils class and access it from every class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new `GraphicsUtil` class and add such utilitarian methods as `static` there. Such util methods do not belong to any one class and make more sense to be made available globally to the application through a static/global context.

All other graphics classes would then use it as

```
int alpha = GraphicsUtil.getAlphaValue(50);
```

Answer (score 1):

No copying ever! That's why we use `Object-oriented` programming nowadays, to avoid code duplication.

Just make this method public/protected.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud give more information about the two classes. 
Looking at the method, it should become static, because it does not use instance variables.
So you don't have to keep it duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

step 1 : create a third class

step 2 : write that method

step 3 : in your classes call that method with object reference of your newly created class

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is an anti-pattern. If you have a bug in your method, you will have to fix it twice.
The second approach is better, but I would go for a 3rd approach:
Have your 2 classes inherit from the same base class, and have the method in that class. No need to make it protected!